# Can an Alfine 11 replace a Nexus 8?

Tags: folding-bicycle, nexus

An online store currently offers the Dahon Curve XL with a Shimano Nexus 8 IGH (The Dahon site shows the [Nexus 7 model](http://dahon.com/mainnav/folding-bikes/single-view/bike/curve_xl.html)).

I'd like to replace it with an Alfine 11.

Does someone know if the OLD (Over Locknut Distance) is the same, and whether it could be an easy replacement?
http://www.sheldonbrown.com/nexus-mech.html

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As @Kibbee has stated the IGHs do have a different OLD, although Nexus hubs can be spaced out to 135mm with spacers/ bolts/ washers.

***You need to measure the Dahon's rear dropout spacing.***

I can't find anything to suggest otherwise so I assume it's 132mm, in line with other commuter type bikes.

The limiting factor is dropout spacing. The Dahon is an aluminum frame with short chainstays. Both of these essentially prevent the ability to spread the dropouts and force a wider hub in. Aluminum is brittle and not malleable like steel, it doesn't like being bent.

You may damage your frame and void the warranty.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Shimano site is kind of confusing. There are 2 alfine models listed.

[SG-S700-S](http://cycle.shimano-eu.com/content/seh-bike/en/home/city---comfort/drivetrain/internal-geared-hubs/sg-s700-s.html)

[SG-S501-S](http://cycle.shimano-eu.com/content/seh-bike/en/home/city---comfort/drivetrain/internal-geared-hubs/sg-s501-s.html)

The first has an axle length of 187mm, and an over locknut distance of 135mm

The second has an axle length of 135mm and an over locknut distance of 187mm

I think they might have swapped the measurements.

There are 2 Nexus 8 speed hubs that I found.

[SG-8C31](http://cycle.shimano-eu.com/content/seh-bike/en/home/city---comfort/drivetrain/internal-geared-hubs/sg-8c31.html)

[SG-8R36](http://cycle.shimano-eu.com/content/seh-bike/en/home/city---comfort/drivetrain/internal-geared-hubs/sg-8r36.html)

They both show measurements of 132mm axle length, and 184mm over locknut distance. This is a difference of 3 mm in both axle length and over locknut distance.

I don't have enough knowledge to say whether or not that is close enough to be compatible. Perhaps with this information somebody else who is more experienced in this could speak to whether or not they are compatible.